# PHP function_exists/class_exists equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I am looking for an alternative of these two functions in asp.net/c#.

```
if(function_exists('foo'))
{
    $returned = foo($bar);
}
if(class_exists('foo'))
{
    $fooclass = new foo($bar);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("assemblyAddress");

bool containClass = assembly.GetTypes().Where(x=>x.Name == "ClassName").Count() > 0;

bool containmethod = assembly.GetTypes().Where(
    x => x.GetMethods().Count(p => p.Name == "MethodName") > 0).Count() > 0;
```

Comment: This code can be used for checking on runtime no need to compile. Am I right?

Comment: @PeachLabs, It can be used in runtime, I didn't know what you are saying about compile, each code before running need to be compiled.

Answer (score 2):

Such functions are irrelevant, since C# is a static language.
If the class doesn't exist, you'll get a *compile-time* error.

You may be looking for reflection.

Comment: I am trying to develop a plug-in framework like wordpress so trying to get the best possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing does not translate from the interpreted and dynamically typed world to the largely compiled and strongly typed world of .NET. That said, there are other ways to get there, perhaps you might want to restate the question showing what effect you'd like to create.

Answer (score 0):

All functions in C# must exist within a class, so the first example doesn't apply in the context of global functions.

For the case of a class, you will know at compile time if it exists:

```
MyClass x = new MyClass();
```

will return an at compile time if `MyClass` isn't defined.

If you want to get a list of methods that belong to MyClass, you can use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):